# Does it make sense to do VLAD encoding on top of features extracted with CNNs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, feature-selection, image-processing, anomaly-detection

I have a deep learning framework which extracts features of patches of my images and builds a dictionary with PCA and then k-Means. Then the framework detects anomalies based on the distance of the feature vector from test images to these codewords in the dictionary.

Building the dictionary looks like this:

Patch Extraction --> Feature Extraction with CNN--> PCA --> k-Means

My thought would be to add VLAD Encoding to the Feature Extraction, so that I kind of get a dictionary of VLAD vectors:

Patch Extraction --> Feature Extraction and VLAD Encoding --> PCA --> k-Means

Can this make the feature representation of the patches better and possibly improve anomaly detection?